# What is the most optimal way to use ArrayFormula() to Count non-Blanks Where Column Header Matches Row Value?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

What I'm attempting to do is count the number of blank cells across a dataset where the header of the row matches an array.

```
=countifs(D1:AZ,D2:AZ,D1:1,A2)
```

However, it appears that since the array sizes are different, it can't use it as a lookup.
[image]

Ideally, I'd be able to get an array formula to count the number of non-blank cells that correspond to each date in A2:A, like this:
[image]

Looking at the documentation for [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en), I don't see anything about it not being able to handle vertical and horizontal matching.

Also, I need to avoid using =query(), since there may be instances in D1:1 where a date is missing. I will be handling that with an iferror().

Any help/advice you all could provide would be greatly appreciated!

I have made an [editable copy of the dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WaFutH36e9KBzJxSqpeM-0DQOQNxoIBkJPOysKC1WDI/edit?usp=sharing) here for reference.

Thanks

Comment: Just to check I understood your need. You want to count the non-blanks in each column and display it in each row of column B?

Comment: Hey @Jorge, that's right. For 11/5/2018, for instance, there are 2 non-blank cells in the column with the same header. That value is what I'd like to return for each of the values in the A2:A array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It is a matrix multiplication formula that sums up the nonblank cells for each column. It should work for you.

=arrayformula(mmult(transpose(if(D1:1="",0,if(isblank(D2:BG),0,1))),sign(ROW(D2:BG))))

I can explain it if you are interested.

EDIT: How about this? It adds a vlookup.
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(A2:A,{transpose(D1:1),mmult(transpose(if(D1:1="",0,if(isblank(D2:BF),0,1))),sign(ROW(D2:BF)))},2,false)))

Comment: Hello @Eliana, the reason I couldn't do just a simple calculation like that or a pivot table off of the data set is because there might be instances where one of the headers from D2:2 is missing. An example would be the 'Matrix Calculation' worksheet. There's no 11/7 in D1:1. However, the array formula is putting the values from 11/8 in the 11/7 slot, since it's working on ordinal position.

Comment: I see it now, and it works perfectly! Thanks so much! I can see how that one would return the results expected.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a way to do it, on B2:

```
=COUNTIFS(OFFSET($D$2:$D,,MATCH(A2,$D$1:$AZ$1,0)-1),">0")
```

Then you auto fill down, the idea is:

- `MATCH(A2,$D$1:$AZ$1,0)` Will match each date on column A to the date on row 1 and return an index (from 1 to N).
- `OFFSET($D$2:$D,,N)` Will take the range D2:D and offset N columns (In this case the output of MATCH).
- Finally `COUNTIFS` will look for `>0` values in the column which header matches the date on the left.

I hope it helps